# Criteria for combining time series for different departments

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have timeseries data for the number of people who visit a particular department in a company. I have multiple departments as such and I am forecasting the number of people to visit for the next one month for these departments.

Since, there are a lot of departments, there are quite a number of time series models that I am building. I am looking at combining some of these departments so that I have a single timeseries and I forecast on a broader level.

Now, I am looking at certain internal parameters of these departments for making that combining decision, like if the departments do the same kind of work, have the same operational days and so on.

For statistical behaviors, I have tried the below two ways:

1. Correlation between the two time series
2. DTWDistance between multiple departments and selecting series which have the minimum distance.

I have also looked at Granger Causality method as well, but I am not sure if these are relevant to my case.

Could you please help me with that. I would also like to know if there are any other ways in terms of time series behavior that I should look at before trying to combine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the reason for combining the models/depts? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The only reason why I want to do this is because my team feels it would be computationally expensive to deploy multiple models in production, so by combining few departments, it would be an easier deployment.

Comment: Then, all the approaches you suggest look good. Please have a look at the literature for time-series clustering. There are lot's of ideas on how to go for it. Just make sure you use some kind of performance metric in your time-series predictions (e.g. RMSE, MAE, MAPE) and ensure any changes you make to the models minimize the overall error.

Comment: See https://otexts.org/fpp2/hierarchical.html